# Math results in zero. New to coding

Tags: c++

I'm trying to complete an assignment but I'm having difficulty with the math expressions and variables in general. I'm trying to make a program that takes user info on groceries and then outputs a receipt. Here is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    //user input
    string firstItem, secondItem;
    float firstPrice, secondPrice;
    int firstCount, secondCount;

    double salesTax = 0.08675;
    double firstExt = firstPrice * firstCount;
    double secondExt = secondPrice * secondCount;
    double subTotal = firstExt + secondExt;
    double tax = subTotal * salesTax;
    double total = tax + subTotal;


    //user input
    cout << "What is the first item you are buying?" << endl;
    getline(cin, firstItem);
    cout << "What is the price of the " << firstItem << "?" << endl;
    cin >> firstPrice;
    cout << "How many " << firstItem << "s?" <<endl;
    cin >> firstCount;
    cin.ignore();
    cout << "What is the second item you are buying?" << endl;
    getline(cin, secondItem);
    cout << "what is the price of the " << secondItem << "?" << endl;
    cin >> secondPrice;
    cout << "How many " << secondItem << "s?" << endl;
    cin >> secondCount;


    // receipt output
    cout << "1st extended price: " << firstExt << endl;
    cout << "2nd extended price: " << secondExt << endl;
    cout << "subtotal: " << subTotal << endl;
    cout << "tax: " << tax << endl;
    cout << "total: " << total << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The program output either 0 for all or negatives.

Comment: One of the most important principles in coding is: start with something small and simple that works perfectly, then build up. Look at all the time and effort you put into writing this code before you noticed that none of it was working.

Comment: My blunt advice here is read a good book. Do not try to learn by trial and error.

Comment: Also don't tag `C` if your question is about `C++`

Comment: @Beta I did start with something simple. I started with the user input part and made sure that that worked before I started working on the output of the math expressions.

Comment: @ Ajay Brahmakshatriya My bad that was a miss click.

Comment: Your sequence of operation is - `Calculate -> User input -> Output` but it should be - `User input -> Calculate -> Output`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have given that comment more thought before I posted it. The approach I'm suggesting is hard to sum up in this space, but once you knew you had I/O working, your first attempt at calculation could have been `int n; n=n+1; cin >> n; cout << n<< endl;`. The bug would have been much easier to see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your calculations must go after you read in the values, not before. You're making your calculations based on uninitialized variables.

Comment: Wow thanks. That makes sense. Is there anything else that would make my code better?

Comment: @Danny `using namespace std;` at global scope is considered a bad practice in general. Consider qualifying std's stuff with it's namespace name, eg `std::cin` `std::cout` `std::string`. Also, if you want your program to be better separated, consider using functions for your calculations.

Comment: For a homework assignment, I'd say it's decent (besides the `using namespace std` as mentioned). It's good practice to decompose your code into functions, but it's also good practice to know when that's over-engineering for the task at hand :). I'd say that this particular program is simple enough to live in the main function like you have it.

Comment: @Guillaume Racicot Why is `using namespace std` considered a bad practice? Does it cause errors?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice

Answer (score 2):

A declaration and initialisation like

```
double firstExt = firstPrice * firstCount;
```

initialises `firstExt` to be the product of the current values AT THAT POINT of `firstPrice` and `firstCount`.

It doesn't set up some magic so that the value of `firstExt` is recalculated whenever the values of `firstPrice` or `firstCount` are changed.

In your case, `firstPrice` and `firstCount` are uninitialised variables when you do this.  Accessing values of uninitialised variables of type `int` gives undefined behaviour.

What you need to do is something like

```
cout << "What is the price of the " << firstItem << "?" << endl;
cin >> firstPrice;
cout << "How many " << firstItem << "s?" <<endl;
cin >> firstCount;

firstExt = firstPrice*firstCount;   //  do the calculation here
```

If the value of `firstExt` is not needed until this point, you can declare it here instead;

```
double firstExt = firstPrice*firstCount;   //  do the calculation here
```

which means any earlier use of `firstExt` will give a compiler diagnostic.